# Google Chrome issues with impress.js

Tags: impress.js

Sorry for the rather unspecific title, but I can't say it any better.

I'm making a site which works flawlessly (as far as I coded it) in Firefox, but since only insignificant changes it stopped working in Chrome, and I have absolutely no idea why this is! Here's a link to the site, so you can try for yourself:
http://aichorn.com/original

as I started working on it, it worked great in Chrome, but since yesterday it stopped working in Chrome. normally you are supposed to be able to click on "trail-infos" and then a box with a link should fade in. you can get to the box at the moment only by pressing spacebar or clicking on the right arrow...once you are on the trail-info box there's a link saying "Allmountain", and you should be able to click that link. but it simply doesn't work. as if there's an invsible overlay or something, preventing you from clicking! I cant figure out what's the problem, been trying z-index and stuff, but nothing helped! I've undone all changes I made from the last working version, but still it wont work. this is driving me nuts, since i can't find any reason!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Chrome 33.0.1750.154 m and the website is working fine. Could be an issue with your PC or temp internet files (Clear cache cookies etc) to try and get working.

I am able to navagate left through all the different boxes that move in 3D space, Trial Infos allows me to click on the small box and the content loads.. I'm assuming that is meant to the be product.

If not show screenshot comparisons what you are getting on FF and what you are getting on Chrome.

Interesting concept for the website also! Best of luck!

Comment: so you are able to go from startpov to "trail-infos" by clicking on "Trail-Infos"? and then, you are able to click on the "Allmountain"-Link? Does this link work and bring you to an empty grey box? this is where i have issues. the white written, underlined "Allmountain" in the trailbox is supposed to be a link, but neither my cursor is a pointer, nor i can click on this with any impact!
i've emptied my cache, without any effects. also using  the same chrome version! which addons are installed on your chrome? any developer-addons? in firefox, i found out, that it makes a difference!

Comment: Yeah I can no problem. Still Trial, click the first link then a map comes up ofor allmountain

Comment: on a friends computer was the same problem with chrome...strange. anyway, i just solved the problem. i changed the degree of "pre-rotation" of the Trail-Info point to a smaller value (just one degree less!), and now its working. this was definetly the solution...must be a bug of the impress.js! thanks for your help!

Comment: Up Vote and Tick as Answer would be appreciated! D: